# How to rack backend data progress from Angular frontend?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, progress-bar

I have a Java Spring Boot backend with Mongo. The API calls a service class that creates multiple pdf files and puts them into a zip file and sends back to the Controller layer. We get this zip from the Controller by raising an API call from the Angular frontend.

I want to track the progress of pdf generation (e.g. 2 of 100 done). Is there any way to achieve this? I want to show some kind of a progress bar in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a database.

- The service which generates the PDF can continuously (or at certain points) update a tracker database table. (You can go into more details like file name, file size, or time taken)
- While your Angular app can enable a progress bar(or bars) and update it by accessing the database

**Typescript**

```
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      // access a database and update the progress bar
    }, 1000);
// After you are done: clearInterval(this.interval);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width]="percentDone + '%'" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    {{ percentDone }}%
</div></div>
```